# Unable to deploy a Cloud ML model

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Why I try to deploy my trained model to Google Cloud ML, I get the following error:

```
Create Version failed.Model validation failed: Model metagraph does not have inputs collection.
```

What does this mean and how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tensorflow model deployed on CloudML did not have a collection named “inputs”. This collection should name all the input tensors for your graph. Similarly, a collection named “outputs” is required to name the output tensors for your graph. Assuming your graph has two input tensors x and y, and one output tensor scores, this can be done as follows:

```
tf.add_to_collection(“inputs”, json.dumps({“x” : x.name, “y”: y.name}))
tf.add_to_collection(“outputs”, json.dumps({“scores”: scores.name}))
```

Here “x”, “y” and “scores” become aliases to the actual tensor names  (x.name, y.name and scores.name)