# What are the input/output tensors, for the translation(RNN) tutorial?

Tags: tensorflow

As per [Unable to deploy a Cloud ML model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781946/unable-to-deploy-a-cloud-ml-model) if I want to deploy my model to the Google Cloud ML I need explicitly set the "input"/"output" collections that will store the references to the input/output tensors, like this:

> This collection should name all the input tensors for your graph.
>   Similarly, a collection named “outputs” is required to name the output
>   tensors for your graph. Assuming your graph has two input tensors x
>   and y, and one output tensor scores, this can be done as follows:
>
> tf.add_to_collection(“inputs”, json.dumps({“x” : x.name, “y”:
>   y.name})) 
>   tf.add_to_collection(“outputs”, json.dumps({“scores”:
>   scores.name}))
>
> Here “x”, “y” and “scores” become aliases to the actual
>   tensor names (x.name, y.name and scores.name)

However, I do not know what are the input/output tensors in the translation(RNN) [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/translate.py). Without this knowledge, I can't refactor the code and deploy my models to the Google Cloud ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code below, the inputs are: encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, target_weights, and the output is the third element of the output of the return value of step()

https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py#L170